# How to disable logcat Text wrap in Eclipse Juno

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, android-logcat

I'm using the latest Eclipse Juno to develop Android applications.

My problem is that the logcat text messages are wrapped after about 80 characters (even when the Text column is much wider then those 80 characters). This is rather annoying because it wraps one long line in multiple rows, while I'm not even using half of my Logcat Window width, which makes it less readable.

I've looked into the preferences of Eclipse under Android > Logcat but can't find any solution to my problem.
Not long ago I used Eclipse Indigo for my Android development, where the text messages weren't wrapped.

Does anyone know how to disable the wrapping in the Logcat Text column in Eclipse Juno ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can just extend the Text message field to a very high value (e.g. 4000) so that **all** messages that are logged fit into one line right from the start.
This can be accomplished by

- using the colum resizer (righ of the Text column header, hold it down) and (for convenience) the right arrow key (to do the actual resizing). Restart Eclipse to see the effect
- altering the value `logcat.view.colsize.Text=4000` in `$WORKSPACE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs` while Eclipse is closed

Comment: This valus is in pixels not in characters. For me it is 649, but it still wraps the text. :(

Comment: Your first option worked for me. Resizing the **Text** column in the **LogCat** view to the right, so that you have to scroll to the right. After that I only have to switch to another **Saved filter** and back to the **All messages (no filters)**, and all line breaks were gone! I didn't set any configuration options, nor did I restart my eclipse (Luna).

Answer (score 1):

This actually came with some ADT version, not with Juno and you cannot really fix it. The only thing you can do is to use the deprecated Logcat View or the commandline.

Alternatively you can also try to make the text column as big as possible.

Comment: Changing the column width has no effect actually