# Eclipse Android Logcat: How can I save my preferences of showing specific info columns in Logcat?

Tags: android, eclipse, preferences, logcat

Forgive me for not displaying Logcat in full size (I'm using a VM with limited RAM and graphics memory, as of now).

On every occasion, whenever I start up my Eclipse, the Logcat would look like this, with all of these info columns showing (Circled in red).

[image: Default info columns displaying in Logcat.]

Now, I would like to save my preferences in Logcat, so that it would be like this (Circled in blue) whenever I start up Eclipse.

[image: My saved preferences in Logcat.]

Does anyone know how to do this instead of closing the info columns every single time? If this isn't available, can we request it as a feature somewhere?

I can take any answers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/14144413, you can manually set the pixel width of each column. So set the column you don't want to see to 1.

I tried rearranging the order in the com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs file but that did not affect the ordering in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

After countless searching in Google, I have come to the conclusion that there is no workaround for this problem.

The only possible way would be to ask for this as a feature request.